# Merging two Sequences in xsl

Tags: xslt, merge, sequence

- The two sequences of elements which are sorted by increasing. ,  xsl outputs one sequence containing all the items and sorted them increasingly.

input:

```
<!DOCTYPE lists SYSTEM "list.dtd">

<numbers>
<list>
   <num val="2"/>
   <num val="5"/>
   <num val="8"/>
   <num val="12"/>
   <num val="20"/>
   <num val="32"/>
</list>
<list>
   <num val="4"/>
   <num val="7"/>
   <num val="10"/>
   <num val="29"/>
   <num val="30"/>
</list>
</numbers>
```

the output should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE lists SYSTEM "list.dtd">
<numbers>
<list>
   <num val="2"/>
   <num val="4"/>
   <num val="5"/>
   <num val="7"/>
   <num val="8"/>
   <num val="10"/>
   <num val="12"/>
   <num val="20"/>
   <num val="29"/>
   <num val="30"/>
   <num val="32"/>
</list>
</numbers>
```

here is my xsl ,the result is wrong ,could you show it for me??

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

 <xsl:output method="xml"  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent ="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
 <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="lists">
  <xsl:copy>
  <list>
    <xsl:call-template name="merge">
      <xsl:with-param name ="num1" select="list[1]/item" as="element(item)*"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="num2" select ="list[2]/item" as="element(item)*"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
   </list>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="merge" as="element(item)*">
<xsl:param name="num1" as="element(item)*"/>
<xsl:param name="num2" as="element(item)*"/>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="empty($num1)">
    <xsl:sequence select="$num2"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="empty($num2)">
    <xsl:sequence select="$num1"/>
   </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$num2[1]/@val ge $num1[1]/@val">
      <xsl:sequence select="$num1[1]"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="merge">
        <xsl:with-param name="num1"  select="$num1[position()>1]"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="num2" select="$num2[1]"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:sequence select="$num2[1]"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="merge">
          <xsl:with-param name="num1" select="$num1[1]"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="num2"  select="$num2[position()>1]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>

   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="numbers">
        <xsl:copy>
         <list>
            <!--process all of the num elements -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="list/num">
            <!--Sort the num elements by @val, as number to ensure proper sort order-->
                <xsl:sort select="number(@val)"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
         </list>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Identity template - copies content forward by default -->
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

If you don't want to use `xsl:sort`, and want to use your stylesheet and custom "merge" template, there are a couple of adjustments that you need to make in order for it to work with the sample input.  Below is a corrected version with some inline comments explaining where the adjustments were made:

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

    <xsl:output method="xml"  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent ="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Issue#1: This was matching on "lists" -->
    <xsl:template match="numbers">
        <xsl:copy>
            <list>
                <xsl:call-template name="merge">
                    <!--Issue#2: these parameters were restricted to "item", not "num" -->
                    <xsl:with-param name ="num1" select="list[1]/num" as="element(num)*"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="num2" select ="list[2]/num" as="element(num)*"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </list>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Issue#3: these output restricted to "item", not "num" -->
    <xsl:template name="merge" as="element(num)*">
        <!--Issue#4: these parameters were restricted to "item", not "num" -->
        <xsl:param name="num1" as="element(num)*"/>
        <xsl:param name="num2" as="element(num)*"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="empty($num1)">
                <xsl:sequence select="$num2"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="empty($num2)">
                <xsl:sequence select="$num1"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <!--Issue#5: These values need to be evaluated as numbers, string compare will give you bad results(e.g. "10" is less than "8") -->
            <xsl:when test="number($num2[1]/@val) ge number($num1[1]/@val)"> 
                <xsl:sequence select="$num1[1]"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="merge">
                    <xsl:with-param name="num1"  select="$num1[position()>1]"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="num2" select="$num2"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:sequence select="$num2[1]"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="merge">
                    <xsl:with-param name="num1" select="$num1"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="num2"  select="$num2[position()>1]"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>

        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: @Mads Hansen:thanks for your help,but if i do not want to use<xsl:sort>,how can I do it?

Comment: Why not use `xsl:sort`?  Why re-create a sort solution when there is an out-of-the-box solution?

Comment: @Mads Hansen:En ,yeah,<xsl:sort> is a good way ,but I want to take the first item of both sequences at the same time and compare their attributes.Create a new template??

Comment: @ZAWD: If you want a zip pattern sorting pairs, you should post a better input and output example.

Comment: @Mads Hansen:En.Actually,I want to accomplish the transformation whicha I have made.The result is wrong ,could you showed my mistake for me?? Thank you!

Comment: @ZAWD I've updated the answer with a corrected version of your stylesheet with embedded comments explaining the changes.

Comment: @Mads Hansen :thanks again for your help ,but there is still something wrong here,I think the out put is not right,you see the output ,the order of numbers are"2,4,5,7,8,29,12,30,20,32",but our expect resuslt is "2,4,5,7,8,12,20,29,30,32 ".

Comment: @Mads Hansen:I think the problem is here:<xsl:sequenceselect="$num1[1]"/><xsl:sequence select="$num2[1]"/>  here, we output them at the same time ,but when the num2[1] is lager than num1[2],the result will be wrong.

Comment: @ZAWD I updated the stylesheet to put back some of your original logic. It produces the example output from your question. `<xsl:sort>` would be much easier/simple.

Comment: @Mads Hansen: thank you!!But could you explain the "number()" function for me??why the "integer()" can not work?

Comment: `number()` converts a string to a (double) number, or "NaN". XSLT doesn't have an `integer()` function.

Comment: @Mads Hansen：and how about if the elements of list are not in the order,what can i do at first and without <xsl:sort>.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@data-type="number"` to do the sorting:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" doctype-system="list.dtd" />

  <xsl:template match="numbers">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <list>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="list/num">
          <xsl:sort select="@val" data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </list>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```